# calling multiple activities using intent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

This code is not working as expected. I have created 5 activities, and I am using button faq in activity1 to intent activity2. In activity2 I am calling three more activities 3, 4 and 5, and on running the app it is displaying unfortunately stopped. I do not think I am using the intent correctly.

java code for activity1

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.faq);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            // Yes we will handle click here but which button clicked??? We don't know

            // So we will mak
            if(v.getId() == R.id.faq)
            {
                    // do something when the corky is clicked
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

    }}}
```

xml for activity1

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@drawable/educa"
    tools:context="com.example.android.educato.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/faq"
        android:text="frequently asked questions (faq)"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Never stop learning!"
        android:textColor="#DC143C"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="56sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

java code for activity2

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            // Capture our button from layout
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
            Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
            Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
            // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
            button2.setOnClickListener(this);
            button3.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            // Yes we will handle click here but which button clicked??? We don't know

            // So we will make
            switch (v.getId() /*to get clicked view id**/) {
                case R.id.b1:

                    // do something when the corky is clicked
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.b2:

                    // do something when the corky2 is clicked
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main4Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;
                case R.id.b3:

                    // do something when the corky3 is clicked
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main5Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

xml for activity2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/educ"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.educato.Main2Activity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="emergency contact numbers for resident of siliguri"

        />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="mode of admission for iits"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tourist attractions nearby siliguri"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
      ``  android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

logcat: after clicking the button in the app

```
Process: com.example.android.educato, PID: 9131
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.educato/com.example.android.educato.Main2Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2576)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:155)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at com.example.android.educato.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:17)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2576) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:155) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
       at com.example.android.educato.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:17) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2576) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:155) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
       at com.example.android.educato.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:17) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2576) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:155) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 814390212 byte allocation with 14818058 free bytes and 170MB until OOM
       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2650)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2555)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
       at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3964)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:574)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
       at com.example.android.educato.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:17) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2576) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:155) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-21 03:16:51.633 9131-9131/com.example.android.educato D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 814390212 byte allocation with 14818058 free bytes and 170MB until OOM` -- You have images that are too large.

Answer (score 1):

As what i seem your problem wasn't about intent. You use it correctly your problem is you setting the layout from your Main2Activity same as your MainActivity.

Just change the code inside Main2Activity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //change this line

    ...your code
}
```

to

```
setContentView(Your Main2Activity Layout);
```

Comment: it is not working even after correcting the argument of setContentView

Comment: @RishabhSaraf what error you get after correcting the setContentView

Comment: android studio is running the app fine, no error msg is being displayed. i even used debugger at the onClick method in the MainActivity.java but it runs fine. on clicking the button in the phone, the app crashes.

Comment: i have added in the description @teckwei

Comment: @RishabhSaraf see this link mayb helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792486/unable-to-start-activity-component-error-binary-xml-file-line-2-error-inflati

Comment: it is not working even after implementing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792486/unable-to-start-activity-component-error-binary-xml-file-line-2-error-inflating

Comment: @cricket_007 can you please help out.

Comment: @RishabhSaraf can u update your MainActivity2 Code for me? just edit the question I wan your current code.